# Is there a spec to show what are all the different data types in clojurescript doing?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to port http://fluokitten.uncomplicate.org/ to clojurescript and its a little bit more complicated than just a one-to-one correspondence between clojure datastructures and cljs datastructues.

The most comprehensive list I found were of clojurescript data-types that are `printable`:
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L6827-L6912

There are some like `PersistentQueue`, `PersistentVector`, `List` that are quite clear. However, types such as `RSeq`, `BlackNode`, `RedNode` and many others in that list are quite foreign to me. Are there any sources of information that can make it easier to understand what these structures do how to access these structures and how to extend them?

Comment: suggestion: RedNode, BlackNode seems to be part of Red-Black Tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any comprehensive documentation about all of the data structures beyond the Clojure and ClojureScript source itself.